# Django: "ImportError: cannot import name on_commit"

Tags: python, django, servidor

Estou tentando rodar uma aplicação em Django, entretanto, quando utilizo o comando `python2 manage.py runserver` tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_cleanup\apps.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import cache, handlers
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_cleanup\handlers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.transaction import on_commit
ImportError: cannot import name on_commit
```

Estou utilizando as seguintes versões:

Python 2.7
Django 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Se você ler a [documentação de `django.db.transaction.on_commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) verá que a funcionalidade só foi adicionada no Django 1.9.

Lembre-se de checar se você está vendo a documentação correta, no seu caso a [documentação do Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/).